# investigate the function $y=e^{\frac{(x-a)^2}{b^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Investigate and graph  $y=e^{\frac{(x-a)^2}{b^2}}$ when $a>0$ and $a>\frac{|b|}{\sqrt{2}}$

What I have done is to understand the power so I got $-2a^2<b^2<2a^2$ but how this and the other facts can help me investigate the function?

is it just $e^x$ or $e^{-x}$?

Comment: It is not $e^x$, and it is not $e^{-x}$. It is what it says it is, and you might try choosing some values of $a$ and $b$ that meet the restrictions, and then try to graph the function.

Comment: so for example I take $b=a^2$ so I get $e^{\frac{x^2-2ax+a^2}{a^2}}$ it is more like $e^{\frac{c}{d}}$

Comment: I don't know what you mean. $e^{c/d}$ is a number. $e^{(x^2-2ax+a^2)/a^2}$ is a function of $x$. Look: let $a=b=2$ and graph it. It won't look like $e^x$, and it won't look like $e^{-x}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see, so it is $e^{\frac{P[x]}{P[x]}}$ where P[x]=polynomial

Comment: @gbox No.  Actually, the denominator is never a polynomial of $x$.  It's simply $b^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us observe the following function $f(x)$.$$f(x)=e^{x^2}$$It appears to have a sort of exponential look, noting that since $x^2\ge0$, this graph has a minimum of $f_{minimum}=1$.  From there, the graph always increases.

Now, consider $f(x-a)$.  We get the following:$$f(x-a)=e^{(x-a)^2}$$There is nothing special, simply a horizontal shift of the graph.

Now consider $f^{1/b^2}(x)$.$$f^{1/b^2}(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{b^2}}=e^{(\frac xb)^2}=f(\frac xb)$$Once again, nothing special.  Simply a horizontal stretching of the graph.

Considering $f(\frac{x-a}b)$?  It is simply a horizontal shift of $a$ followed by a stretch of $b$.

Do excuse if my terminology isn't perfect, but that is the gist of it.

So regardless of what you do, all of what I've said is true, therefore, observing $f(x)$ is all that is necessary to understand the graph you are looking at.

As you may have noticed, the graph is appears to be symmetrical.  That is because it is even, and we prove it the following way.$$f(x)=f(-x)$$$$e^{x^2}=e^{(-x)^2}$$

The statement is true, therefore it is an even function and symmetrical in what you have noticed to be a "U" shape.

To explain why it is in a "U" shape and not in some other shape, we have to know a little bit of calculus.

If the following is true, then the graph will be in a "U" shape, bending upwards.$$f^{(2)}(x)>0$$This means that the second derivative must be greater than $0$ for all $x$.  If this is true, the function has the property of bending upwards, creating a "U" shape.

$$f'(x)=2xe^{x^2}$$$$f^{(2)}(x)=f''(x)=2e^{x^2}+4x^2e^{x^2}=(2+4x^2)e^{x^2}$$

We note that if $2+4x^2>0$ and $e^{x^2}>0$, then $f^{(2)}>0$.  We note that for $2+4x^2<0$, $x$ isn't a real number.  The same is true for $e^{x^2}$.  Therefore, since we are only dealing with real numbers, the second derivative is greater that $0$ for all real $x$.

Which describes $f(x)$ as a function that always bends upwards, in a "U" shape.

Comment: Feel free to ask if you notice anything else peculiar about your graph.

Comment: $e^{x^2}$ is an even function, but the shifted function OP asks about is not.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, yes, I know.  But it does explain the "U" shape-ness of the function.  I've also explained how my function relates to the OP's function.